# RxJS retry and then catchError not working

Tags: error-handling, rxjs, observable, nestjs

I have an observable:

```
public updateThingName(name: string, thingId: number): Observable<any> {
    console.log('attempting rename');
    return this.http
        .put(
          `${this.thingApi}/projects/${thingId}`, 
          { name },
          this.options,
      ).pipe(
          map(response => response.data.id)
      );
}
```

called as part of a longer chain:

```
    return this.projectService.getProject(id).pipe(
            switchMap(prevProjectData => {
                return this.projectService.updateProject(id, data).pipe(
                    map(newProjectData => ({prevProjectData, newProjectData}))
                )
            }),
            switchMap(({prevProjectData, newProjectData}) => {
                return this.thingService.updateThingName(newProjectData.title, newProjectData.thingId)
                  .pipe(retry(5),catchError(err => {
                      return this.projectService.revertProjectUpdate(err, prevProjectData);
                }))
            }),
            tap(() => { ... save to logs only when successful ... })
        );
```

I want to try to rename something, if it fails retry 5 times, if it still fails then catch the error, revert the earlier changes and throw the final error in the revert function. The reverting and sending the error response back to the front end works fine but no matter where I put the `retry(5)` I only ever see the initial `console.log('attempting rename');` in the logs.

Am I miss using the retry? How do I get this to work?

This is backend code on NestJS so I don't handle the final subscribe aspects directly if that makes a difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be correct. The methodos called once but it tries to resubscribe multiple times. You should be able to see it if you log a message on every subscribe:

```
public updateThingName(name: string, thingId: number): Observable<any> {
  return defer(() => {
    console.log('attempting rename');
    return this.http
      .put(
        `${this.thingApi}/projects/${thingId}`, 
        { name },
        this.options,
    ).pipe(
        map(response => response.data.id)
    );
  )};
}
```

Comment: Yes, that now shows the logs for the number of retries. the penny has just dropped on this, it is only retrying the observable and not the method. by wrapping it in defer and returning that i now get to see the log as it is part of the returned observable